# maxlength in textarea not working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, textarea, maxlength

I'm using maxlength in my form but it is throwing the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxlength' of null

Part of the form where I'm using maxlength:

```html
<div>
   <textarea AutoExpandTextArea [inputData]='model.title' maxlength="100" class="videoTitle" name="videoTitle" id="videoTitle" #videoTitle="ngModel"  placeholder="Title" [(ngModel)]="model.title" required>{{model.title}}</textarea>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="submitted && loginform.form.invalid && videoTitle.errors.required">Title is mandatory</span>
  <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="videoTitle.dirty && videoTitle?.errors.maxlength">Maximum 100 characters are allowed</span>
   <textarea AutoExpandTextArea [inputData]='model.description' maxlength="120" class="videoDescription" id="videoDescription" name="videoDescription" #videoDescription="ngModel" placeholder="Description" [(ngModel)]="model.description">{{model.description}}</textarea>
   <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="videoDescription.dirty && videoDescription?.errors.maxlength">Maximum 120 characters are allowed</span>

</div>
```

The model object looks like this when the page loads

```
this.model = {
            description: '',
            title: '',
        }
```

As soon as I type something into the textarea the error starts to come up.

I have a directive also bound to the textarea. Not sure if that is causing the problem.

Comment: I don't know if it's causing your error, but shouldn't the attribute values all be using double quotes?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: the quotes are not causing the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's complaining about the length of something that doesn't exist yet: videoDescription?.errors.

You can add the safe navigation operator after `errors` videoDescription.errors?.maxLength. Like in this example:

**HTML**

```
 <textarea required maxlength="10" 
    name="titleId" [ngModel]="titleModel" 
    (ngModelChange)="titleModel = $event + ''" #titleId="ngModel" ></textarea> 

 <span style="color:red" *ngIf="titleId.errors?.required">
          required
 </span>
 <span style="color:red" *ngIf="titleId.errors?.maxlength">
          10 max
 </span>
```

**Typescript**

```
titleModel= 'I have more than 10 characters'
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1qvgn)**

This works, but maxLength prevents entering more characters after the limit, so the validation message will be show only if you set it programatically.

---

If you wish to let the user enter and then react, you can forgo with this kind of implementation:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="title" maxlength="10" 
name="title" [(ngModel)]="titleModel"></textarea> 
<span style="color:red" *ngIf="titleModel?.length > 10">
      10 max
</span>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u2xbmy)

Comment: i knew but wanted to know if it will work with normal angular validation.For some reason angular validation i.e error.maxlength (with or without the safe navigation) did not work.So i had to use the length of the model value.

Comment: that is an input not a textarea.The issue is with textarea.inputs work fine!

Comment: Your plunkr for the React example contains invalid attributes. fixed [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/4QomnLXGSxTW63ho8w1k?p=preview)

Comment: While I agree with type="number", which is 'leftover' from something I don't remember, maxlength attribute is valid, though not used

Comment: Agreed, maxlength is a valid attribute but it prevents more than 10 characters from being entered into the textarea, so the validation error will never be triggered. Either the HTML5 maxlength attribute or Angular maxLength validator should be used, but not both IMO (can't find any documentation supporting this).